# Why do inline elements wrap on small screens?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an input field with div below it. Everything is good when I use my browser , but whenever I try to see it on my phone or any smaller screen it breaks.

I'm using Bootstrap. I tried to use 'vh' insted of 'px' but that didn't help much.

[image: Picture].

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex  ">
  <div class="row  align-self-center ">
    <div class="col-12">
     <span id="icon"></span>
     <input type="text" id="city"></input>

     <br><div id="res" class="nText"> citudin. Praesent hendcongue. Ut commodo 
est ut orci suscipit tincidunt. Sed ac est sed mi tristique sollicongue. Ut 
commodo est ut orci suscipit tincidunt. Sed ac est sed mi tristique 
sollirerit in velit non ullamcorper. Quisque volutpat, justo id lobortis 
finibus, tellus nibh lobortis augue, at semper nisl justo viverra mi.</div>
 </div> 
</div> 
</div><!-- end container-->
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.nText {
background-color: lightgray;
}

.container-fluid {
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
background-color:lightblue;
}


#city {
width: 300px;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to behave the same for all screen sizes. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/9yj8p1rm/

Comment: I'd advise against overriding Bootstrap's CSS for such important elements as `container-fluid`. Instead, add a custom class and use that.

Comment: Are you talking about your fixed width and fixed left padding? Not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly between the sizes.

Comment: Even without the fixed width and left padding the problem remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input field is set to 300px so it's overflowing, if you instead make the maximum width 300px, but set the width to 100% this'll keep it constrained to the size of the page but never any wider than 300px.

https://jsfiddle.net/6u4v0dnq/

```
#city {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```